# Quadratic Variation of Quadratic Variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation

Consider a *good integrator* $X$ (semi-martingale) and the relative *quadratic variation* process indicated by: $Y_t:=[X,X]_t$.

Why is that:

$$[Y,Y]_t=0 \ \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ \ \ \ [X,Y]_t=0 \ \  ?$$

EDIT: I believe that for general good integrators the previous statement is not true.
 Indeed:

If $Y$ is adapted, cadlag, with paths of finite variation on compacts, then Y is a quadratic pure jump semimartingale. Therefore: $[Y,Y]_t=∑_{0<s<t}(ΔY_s)^2$.

Comment: Hint: For which processes $U$ can one be sure that $[U,V]=0$ for every process $V$? The answer should be very near to the *beginning* of your notes.

Comment: @Did I was thinking about $U$ being of Finite Variation but the Q.V. would be 0 just in the case of $U$ being continuous as well.

Comment: just out of curiosity: do you mean the predictable version of the quadratic variation?

Comment: @user190080 no, I mean the quadratic variation for general good integrators

Answer (score 5):

Quadratic variation of a semi-martingale is non-decreasing and right-continuous. (Or at least there exists such a *version* of it). You know that a function is of bounded variation if and only if it is the difference of two non-decreasing functions. So $[X,X]_t$ is of bounded variation and right-continuous. Then its quadratic variation must be the sum of the jumps squared over the interval the Q.V. is computed.

If you impose further that the semi-martingale is continuous, then its Q.V. is continuous as well. The argument above gives in that case a Q.V. of $0$.

Comment: I follow the reasoning and it is what I was thinking after the hint gave by @Did, but: If $Y$ is adapted, cadlag, with paths of finite variation on compacts, then $Y$ is a quadratic pure jump semimartingale. Therefore: $[Y,Y]_t = \sum_{0<s<t}(\Delta Y_s)^2$. So why should this be 0 ?

Comment: @mastro You are absolutely right. One should impose continuity on $X$ to make sure $Y$ is continuous as well. Then the QV of $Y$ is $0$.

Comment: but why is $[X,X]$ difference of increasing functions?

Comment: $[X,X]$ is non-decreasing itself. Then just write it as $[X,X] - 0$ where $0$ is a stochastic process that is almost surely $0$ at all time instants, which is clearly also non-decreasing.

Comment: @mastro to see that $[X,X]$ is non-decreasing is, since you use the sum definition of the quadratic variation, not hard. Maybe a small remark, functions which are non-decreasing are of finite variation

Answer (score 0):

Quadratic variation of a quadratic variation is **quartic variation**, i.e.,
$$ [[X,X],[X,X]] = \sum_{t\leq\cdot}(\Delta X_t)^4. $$

More generally,
*Emery, Michel*, [**Stabilité des solutions des équations différentielles stochastiques. Application aux intégrales multiplicatives stochastiques**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00534242), Z. Wahrscheinlichkeitstheor. Verw. Geb. 41, 241-262 (1978). [ZBL0351.60054](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0351.60054)
has shown that for a $\mathcal{C}^2$ function $\xi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\xi(0)=0$, the quantity
$$\int_0^\cdot \xi(dX_t) := \xi'(0)(X_t-X_0)+\frac{1}{2}\xi''(0)[X,X]^c+\sum_{t\leq\cdot}(\xi(\Delta X_t)-\xi'(0)\Delta X_t)$$
is the $\xi$-variation of $X$.

For nice enough $\psi$ and $\xi$, the variations compose, i.e., the $\psi$-variation of the $\xi$-variation of $X$ is equal to the $\psi(\xi)$-variation of $X$. The proof is given, for example, in
*Carr, Peter; Lee, Roger*, [**Variation and share-weighted variation swaps on time-changed Lévy processes**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00780-013-0212-9), Finance Stoch. 17, No. 4, 685-716 (2013). [ZBL1275.91129](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1275.91129).

Hence quadratic variation of a quadratic variation is quartic variation.

One can extend the composition rule to predictable variations and build a simplified stochastic calculus as a result. For example, the Ito formula for $f(X)$ is a predictable variation of $X$ by means of the predictable function $\xi(x) = f(X_-+x)-f(X_-)$. For more details, see
*Černý, Aleš; Ruf, Johannes*, [**Simplified stochastic calculus via semimartingale representations**](https://doi.org/10.1214/21-EJP729), Electron. J. Probab. 27, Paper No. 3, 32 p. (2022). [ZBL1490.60103](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1490.60103).