# Confusion about the difference of quadratic variations and the Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integral

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider a path of finite quadratic variation $\omega$ on some fixed time horizon $[0,T]$ and $f$ a function of paths on $\mathbb R$

let $[ \omega ](t)$ be the quadratic variation of the path $\omega$ at $t\in [0,T]$. I recently saw a note, stating that

$\int f d[\omega]=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{t_{i} \in \pi^{n}}f(\omega(t_{i}))(\omega(t_{i+1})-\omega(t_{i}))^{2}$

where $\int f d[\omega]$ is in actual fact the Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integral namely: $\int f d[\omega]=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{t_{i} \in \pi^{n}}f(\omega(t_{i}))([\omega](t_{i+1})-[\omega](t_{i}))$

My question is why are then the following equal:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{t_{i} \in \pi^{n}}f(\omega(t_{i}))(\omega(t_{i+1})-\omega(t_{i}))^{2}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{t_{i} \in \pi^{n}}f(\omega(t_{i}))([\omega](t_{i+1})-[\omega](t_{i}))$$

source of my confusion: how can

$$(\omega(t_{i+1})-\omega(t_{i}))^{2}=\omega(t_{i+1})^{2}-2\omega(t_{i+1})\omega(t_{i})+\omega(t_{i})^{2} $$

and

$$([\omega](t_{i+1})-[\omega](t_{i}))$$

be equal (even in the limit)?

Comment: What is your definition of the quadratic variation $[\omega]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just my try on the question given that it hasn't received any answers yet.

I will assume that $f$, $\omega$ and $[\omega]$ are bounded otherwise you can use stopping times such that this assumption holds and then make passage to infinity.

$$E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^m f(\omega(t_{i}))\{(\omega(t_{i+1})-\omega(t_{i}))^2-([\omega](t_{i+1})-[\omega](t_{i}))\}\right)^2\right]$$

$$\leq  E\left(\sum_{i=1}^m f(\omega(t_{i}))^2\{(\omega(t_{i+1})-\omega(t_{i}))^2-([\omega](t_{i+1})-[\omega](t_{i}))\}^2\right)$$

$$\leq 2\|f\|_{\infty}^2 E\left(\sum_{i=1}^m (\omega(t_{i+1})-\omega(t_{i}))^4+\sum_{i=1}^m([\omega](t_{i+1})-[\omega](t_{i}))^2\right)$$

$\sum_{i=1}^m (\omega(t_{i+1})-\omega(t_{i}))^4$ tends to $0$ when the mesh of the partition goes to $0$, see for example Lemma $1.5.10$ on Karatzas' book.

The second term is (letting the mesh go to $0$) the *quadratic variation of the quadratic variation*, if $\omega$ is continuous, then the latter is $0$. (see the following [Quadratic Variation of Quadratic Variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362102/quadratic-variation-of-quadratic-variation))
(of course in order to take limits inside the expectation I am using some bounded convergence result)

Then you have that the expressions converge in quadratic mean.

Hopefully you'll find this useful even though it's not a proper answer; if you notice something off about it please let me know!

EDIT: As pointed out by @TheoreticalEconomist the application of the Cauchy-Schwarz was not suitable for this particual case. Instead notice that the cross-products are neglected in the first step. For an explanation on this particular see theorem $1.5.8$ on Karatzas' book, and the following discussion.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I've corrected it, actually the cross-products can be neglected, the proof is somehow complex, do you think it's worthy to put it in here?

Comment: on the second equality I am applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $(a-b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)$